# VBA Text Box Date Format

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of controls, buttons, check boxes, etc scattered over a bunch of cells in an excel sheet.  I'd like to replace all this mess with controls in a large single cell with the controls linked to sheet cells.  This all seems quite possible except for dates.  If I link a text box to a cell containing a date such as =NOW(), the text box displays the internal representation of the date rather than something that looks like a date to the user.  The cell the text box links to is formatted as a date.

Is there anyway to cause the date to be displayed in text box linked to a cell?

Is there some code I can add attach to the text box to do this?

Note there is no form involved, just controls on a sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misinterpreting, but you essentially want a text box that can display a date? To get the following, I used an ActiveX text box, selected it and changed the formula from `=EMBED("Forms.TextBox.1","")` to `=A1`:

[image]

This (so far) reflects the format in the underlying cell.

Comment: No prob! Glad it works (also realizing now that my graphic design skills aren't really that great :) ).